# Accessing "protected" part of object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the variable `$customerData` that stores an object. When I execute `print_r($customerData)` I get something similar to the below.

```
Balanced\Customer Object(
    [_collection_uris:protected] => Array(
        [reversals] => Array(
            [class] => Balanced\Reversal
            [uri] => /v1/customers/1234123412341234/reversals
        )
    )
    [_member_uris:protected] => Array(
        [source] => Array(
                [class] => Balanced\Card
                [uri] => /v1/customers/1234123412341234/cards/987698769876
            )
    )
    [_type] => customer
    [twitter] => twitterHandle
    [phone] => 5551231234
)
```

I'm having issues accessing the `uri` inside `_member_uris:protected`.

```
print_r($customerData->_member_uris:protected); #Throws error "unexpected ':'"
print_r($customerData->_member_uris); #Throws error " Undefined property"
print_r($customerData['_member_uris']); #Throws error "Cannot use object of type array"
```

What is the process of accessing that part of the object?

Comment: Protected properties can only be accessed from the class or classes that inherit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. You could add a method in your class to get it, using [setAccessible()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php),  like:

```
//function inside your class
public static function getProtectedProp($class, $propName) {
    $reflClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
    $property = $reflClass->getProperty($propertyName);
    $property->setAccessible(true);     
    return $property->getValue($class);
}
```

and you can do:

```
getProtectedProp($someClassObject, 'protectedPropertyName');
```

Source:: [Reading Protected Property](http://ajmm.org/2011/06/using-php-reflection-to-read-a-protected-property/)

Comment: awesome. Thank you! timer is 7 min

Comment: I'm having issues translating your answer to code I can use. If I am in the method that returns the object above. `$cardsUrl = $returnData->_member_uris`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access protected or private properties from global code or regular functions. From the documentationof [Visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> - Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere.
> - Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes.
> - Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.